# sda1 on CentOS 7 on Google Cloud full id of nothing?

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space, google-compute-engine

I am on Google Cloud Linux CentOS 7.0 Guest. I'm running out of disk! How is this possible? I don't use 25% that they say I do? It looks more like about ~10Gb.

```shell
# du --max-depth=1 --human-readable / | sort --human-numeric-sort
0       /dev
0       /media
0       /mnt
0       /opt
0       /proc
0       /root
0       /srv
0       /sys
4.0K    /tmp
14M     /home
18M     /etc
145M    /boot
193M    /run
1.5G    /usr
3.7G    /var
5.5G    /
```

Yet `df` is showing 41G used? Where is the extra 30Gb?

```shell
# df-H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        43G   41G  2.4G  95% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  202M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           372M     0  372M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Why are you using `--max-depth=1`? That's only 1 directory level under ``/``

Comment: Try using ``du -ah /``